# FXML Java error

Tags: java, fxml

Hola buenas estoy aprendiendo un poco la implementación del FXML
Tengo el siguiente código en FXML:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="pingsdesktop.FXMLController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="j1" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#marked" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="ASDASDASDSD">
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Y en el cotroller tengo este:

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private Button j1;
    
    @FXML
    private void loadButtons(){
        j1.setSize(2, 4);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        
    }    
}
```

Y en el main esto:

```
public class PingsDesktop extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        
        Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta todo esto, no me para de fallar la aplicación por el FXML por el #Marker o por la id del botón y ya no se que hacer.

¿Porqué me pasa esto?

El error es el siguiente en la linea 9 osea donde en el FXML esta creado el button.

```
Executing C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ProvesAlex\PingsDesktop\dist\run2104417432\PingsDesktop.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre/bin/java
mar 15, 2021 2:49:47 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 15.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.111
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el error? Te recomiento completar el [tour] de bienvenida para entender cómo esperamos las preguntas y qué es un [mcve]

Comment: Sin más detalles me da la impresión que estás usando JavaFX versión 15 con JDK 8, que no son compatibles. JavaFx 11 y posteriores necesitan [al menos JDK 11](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/doc-files/release-notes-15.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El namespace en el FXML dice

`http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1`

y muy seguramente estás compilando o corriendo esto sobre un JDK 8.

Así pues, o cambias el namespace en el FXML o instalas otro JDK versión 11 o posterior y lo usas